# mongoDB group by nested document with unknown path

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i want group by value and my problem is screen_size and screen_resulation is changeable

is there is something like wildcard in nested document in mongodb ?

i have tried this but its not working

```
[
    {
      filters: {
        screen_size: {
          name: "حجم الشاشة",
          value: "50",
        },
        screen_resulation: {
          name: "دقة الشاشة",
          value: "4k",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      filters: {
        screen_resulation: {
          name: "دقة الشاشة",
          value: "UHD",
        },
        screen_size: {
          name: "حجم الشاشة",
          value: "55",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      filters: {
        screen_resulation: {
          name: "دقة الشاشة",
          value: "4k",
        },
        screen_size: {
          name: "حجم الشاشة",
          value: "55",
        },
      },
    },
  ];



{
$group : {
 _id: "$filters.*.value", counter: { $sum: 1 }
}
 }
```

Comment: You clear what you are looking for. Can you please provide a sample of expected result.

Comment: i need to group by value , but the parent of value is unknown like screen_size , it may change to something other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result with the below approach as well:

```
[{$project: {
  _id: '$_id',
  filters: { $objectToArray: '$filters' }
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$filters'
}}, {$group: {
  _id: '$filters.v.value',
  count: {$sum: 1}
}}]
```